# Is CloudFront's path pattern wildcard operator * greedy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront

In CloudFront, when I use the wildcard `*` operator, is going to consume as many characters as possible (greedy) or as few (non-greedy)?

In regular expressions there's a difference but I'm not sure about CloudFront.

Specifically if I have

```
*c_*a*
```

I realize that that will match the following filename:

```
ddddc_1111c_ab.png
```

but will it match on the `d`'s or the `1`'s?

Comment: I don't see that specified in manual, so this is a kind of gray area. However I wonder do you see any use case where this will change the way CloudFront behaves? E.g. it deals with pattern matching, not with substring searching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Greediness isn't a factor here, because the only question that must be answered is "does this pattern match the path?"  If it matches, it matches; only if it doesn't match does evaluation continue down the list.  It's an ordered "first match," not a "best match."

> When CloudFront receives an end-user request, the requested path is compared with path patterns **in the order** in which cache behaviors are listed in the distribution. **The first match** determines which cache behavior is applied to that request.
>
> <sup>— http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern (emphasis added)</sup>

---

Note also that when using the AWS console, the ordering of the cache behaviors -- which determines what "first match" means -- can be manually rearranged using the move up/move down buttons, then saving your changes and waiting for the status of the distribution to change from `In Progress` back to `Deployed` -- but after changing this, you may need to do a cache invalidation of `*` so that anything incorrectly cached (because the pattern matching was not configured as intended) will not continue to be cached and served.